# How to create a query in Visual Studio 2013 using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I have the following code and through debugging the problem begins at the While loop. I am trying to retrieve information from 2 tables and insert it into the table created. The information is not being inserted into the table and I am getting blank rows.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class RouteToCruise

    Private Sub RouteToCruise_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Route_Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Route_Btn.Click
        Dim row As String
        Dim connectString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                            "Data Source=M:\ICT-Group-Project\DeepBlueProject\DeepBlueProject\DeepBlueTables.mdb"
        Dim cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connectString)
        cn.Open()
        Dim CruiseQuery As String = "SELECT CruiseID, RouteID FROM Cruise WHERE CruiseID =?"
        Dim RouteQuery As String = "SELECT  RouteName FROM Route WHERE RouteID =?"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(CruiseQuery, cn)
        Dim cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(RouteQuery, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Route_Txt.Text)


        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        'RCTable.Width = Unit.Percentage(90.0)
        RCTable.ColumnCount = 2
        RCTable.Rows.Add()
        RCTable.Columns(0).Name = "CruiseID"
        RCTable.Columns(1).Name = "Route"



        While reader.Read()
            Dim rID As String = reader("RouteID").ToString()
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", rID)

            Dim reader2 As OleDbDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()


            'MsgBox(reader.GetValue(0) & "," & reader.GetValue(1))

            row = reader("CruiseID") & "," & reader2("RouteName")

            RCTable.Rows.Add(row)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


            reader2.Close()
        End While
        reader.Close()
        cn.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Probably a JOIN between the two tables could avoid all this wall of code.

Comment: Hi, Could you edit the code for us as I stuck.

Comment: TABLE THAT i HAVE MADE

Comment: No need to shout. I don't see a declaration, so I don't know what data type it is, nor do I know if it is a simple string, or a grid on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your tables structure well then you could just run a single query extracting data from the two table and joining them in a new table returned by the query

```
Dim sql = "SELECT c.CruiseID c.CruiseID & ',' & r.RouteName as Route " & _
          "FROM Cruise c INNER JOIN Route r ON c.RouteID = c.RouteID " & _
          " WHERE c.CruiseID = @cruiseID"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cruiseID", OleDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Route_Txt.Text)
Dim RCTable = new DataTable()
Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
reader.Load(RCTable)
```

At this point the RCTable is filled with the data coming from the two tables and selected using the Route_Txt textbox converted to an integer. If the CruiseID field is not a numeric field then you should create the parameter as of type OleDbType.VarWChar and remove the conversion to integer

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your query.

```
Dim CruiseRouteQuery As String = "SELECT C.CruiseID, C.RoutID, R.Routename FROM Cruise C LEFT JOIN Route R ON C.RouteID = R.RoutID WHERE CruiseID =?"
```

Also, please let us know what errors you are getting.